# How can i fix my code to prevent the 2 errors in the plurality problem of Week 2 of CS50?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        // If candidate name matches the entered string by voter, then increase vote by 1
        if(strcmp(candidates[i].name,name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // Check which candidate has the most votes
    int highest = candidates[0].votes;
    string highest_candidate = candidates[0].name;

    // For loop to find out most number of votes
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i+1].votes > candidates[i].votes)
        {
            highest = candidates[i+1].votes;
        }
    }

    // For loop to print candidates with the most number of votes
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == highest)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

These are the 2 errors that I encounter when i run check50 to test my code.

```
:) plurality.c exists
:) plurality compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate
:( vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate // Error 1
    vote function did not return false
:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero
:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted
:( vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate // Error 2
    vote function modified vote totals incorrectly
:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
```

I know why Error 1 exists. Its cuz whenever I enter an invalid candidate, it says segmentation fault(core dumped), and exits the program. But I have no idea what that means or how to fix it.

I'm not sure about why Error 2 exists though, as if the vote totals weren't modified correctly, I shouldn't have been able to print the correct winners for each test case.

Comment: One of these loops is not like the other: `for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)` `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)` I wonder why.

Comment: And in that loop `candidates[i+1].votes` will be indexing out of range when `i==8` anyway. *"if the vote totals weren't modified correctly, I shouldn't have been able to print the correct winners for each test case"*. Undefined behaviour can give expected results too.

Comment: So that loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count-1; i++)` and the next hard-coded `9` loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)`. But there is another mistake too: `if (candidates[i+1].votes > candidates[i].votes)` should be `if (candidates[i+1].votes > highest)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- in the `vote` function, the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)` may iterate beyond the number of actual candidates entered, causing undefined behavior when calling `strcmp` with a null pointer for the missing candidate name.
- the same problem in `print_winner` does not cause a problem, but the loops should also stop at `candidate_count`.
- in `print_winner`, you compare `candidates[i+1].votes` and `candidates[i].votes` even for `i = 8`, so you read not only potentially beyond the last candidate entered, but actually beyond the end of the array.
- furthermore, this method only finds the last candidate that has a score greater than the next one, so if 3 candidates have scores `2,1,0`, you would select the 2nd candidate instead of the first.  You should iterate from `1` to `candidate_count`, compare the the current best candidate, for which you would just keep the index, initially set to `0`.
- note also that if 2 candidates have the same name, the second would never get any votes. This condition might be worth checking and reporting.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int votes;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX) {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name)) {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        // If candidate name matches the entered string by voter, then increase vote by 1
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) {
            candidates[i].votes += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void) {
    // Check which candidate has the most votes
    int best = 0;

    // For loop to find out most number of votes
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[best].votes) {
            best = i;
        }
    }

    // For loop to print candidates with the most number of votes
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        if (candidates[i].votes == candidates[best].votes) {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The index was what caused both errors. My code already does work for the 2,1,0 case cuz I already initialized int highest to the no. of votes that candidate 0 has. And as for the same name situation, it is mentioned already in the problem to consider that every voter is unique.