# For CS50 plurality, check50 says that my code doesn't print the winner of the function. But it does?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;

        }
    }
    return 2;

}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int c;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i+1].name == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (candidates[0].votes <= candidates[i+1].votes)
        {
            c = candidates[i+1].votes;
        }
        else
        {
            c = candidates[0].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (c == candidates[i].votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The purpose of the code is to function as a plurality vote. Lets say bob, bill and steve were the candidates. And there were 4 voters. If you put in bob twice, bill in once, and steve in once, bob wins the vote. I got that sort of thing to work. However, when I run check50, it tells me this.

```
:) plurality.c exists
:) plurality compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero
:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted
:) vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate
:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
**:( print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election**
:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
```

That one sad face is the problem. It says it doesn't print the winner of the election, but it does print the winner of the election.

It fully functions as a plurality vote, but its only the check50 thats giving me issues.

Comment: `candidates[i+1].name == NULL` will access outside the array when `i == MAX-1`. This causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `i < candidate_count` instead of `i < MAX` when looping over the candidate array. Then `name` will never be `NULL`.

Comment: This code looks an awful lot like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76642657). The mistakes are not identical but, dare I say, suspiciously similar.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit The structure and function names are given in the problem description, so these being the same is hardly suspicious.

Comment: @Barmar I was talking about the errors, but on the second look they are not that similar. Both programs find the maximum incorrectly, one compares the current score with the first one, the other compares the current with the next. Both programs sometimes loop to the max number of candidates instead of the actual one, but this one breaks when the name is NULL (might be a similar error that the author tried to fix).

Comment: If it is not an error to invoke your program with no arguments, you ought to respond by printing the usage statement and exiting with a value of zero.   If you consider it an error, you ought to print an error message (eg, `fprintf(stderr, ...);`) and exit non-zero.  Whether or not you consider the usage statement to be a valid error message (I do not) is irrelevant; if you exit non-zero, you should print a message to stderr.  IOW, either do `printf(...); exit(0);` or do `fprintf(stderr, ...); exit(1);`.  It is bad practice to exit non-zero without emitting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print_winner` is wrong. It keeps comparing with index zero. It should keep track of the maximum score.

Like:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (candidates[max_index].votes <= candidates[i].votes)
        {
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", candidates[max_index ].name);
    return;
}
```

Further you will also need:

```
candidate candidates[MAX + 1];
```

To make sure there is always a NULL candidate to end your loops. But it would be better to use `candidate_count` in the loops instead of `MAX`. For that you need to adjust the loop conditions.

That said... Don't use those global variables. Pass things as arguments instead.

**Update**

To print all candidates that has the maximum number of votes, you can do:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int max_votes = candidates[0].votes;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (max_votes < candidates[i].votes)
        {
            max_votes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (candidates[i].votes == max_votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[max_index ].name);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: But that print winner doesn't account for ties. Mine does.

Comment: @Harrison No, this doesn't account for ties. True. But yours doesn't work at all so... Anyway it's easy to change this to print all having the same maximum

Comment: it isn't that easy. Your code only tracks one singular max index. Meaning for the code to work, I'd have to track something completely different, like the max number. I did that, and it worked. The only problem I'm having is that the debugger says it doesn't.

Comment: @Harrison See update for an implementation that prints multiple candidates with maximum votes